# How do you track user throughout ASP.NET application and Backend SOA Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

We have an ASP.NET 4 application and using silverlight for some modules. The bulk business of our application is in the services. We currently are using WCF 4 to make calls from UI front end to backend.

I want to track the user's activities while using the application. One way I thought about doing it is to get the session id and user and pass it al of the way through to the back end and log the calls from the main functions to the database.

Does anyone have another idea that is cleaner and more robust?

I know this is not much info, but I need at least a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

See [End-to-End Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738749.aspx), and the following code from [Emitting User-Code Traces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738759.aspx):

```
// Creating Activities
Guid oldID = Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId;
Guid traceID = Guid.NewGuid();
ts.TraceTransfer(0, "transfer", traceID);
Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = traceID; // Trace is static
ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Start, 0, "Add request");

// Emitting Traces within a User Activity
double value1 = 100.00D;
double value2 = 15.99D;
ts.TraceInformation("Client sends message to Add " + value1 + ", " + value2);
double result = client.Add(value1, value2);
ts.TraceInformation("Client receives Add response '" + result + "'");

// Stopping the Activities
ts.TraceTransfer(0, "transfer", oldID);
ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Stop, 0, "Add request");
Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = oldID;
```